# How can I boot a swarm of 50 machines with docker-machine?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I need to boot a bunch of ec2 instances (could be virtualbox instances, doesn't matter) as a swarm. `docker-machine` seems to only work for doing one at a time, and that would take hours to boot 50 machines. I would like to boot the swarm master, and then in parallel boot the 49 swarm workers. This seems like a common use case, but docker-machine has no parameter I can find for the number of instances to boot.

How can I do this? Do I need to just script it myself?

Posted on the docker forums, but typically nobody answers there: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-spin-up-multiple-docker-machines-at-once-i-need-20-or-50-now/8749

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is configuration management software.  Chef, Ansible, Terraform and their competitors were created to deploy and manage clusters like this.

Docker-machine is great for running containers on my MacBook, but not so great for deploying cloud infrastructure.  Look into deploying your swarm into Auto-Scaling Groups with the configuration management tool of your choice.

Comment: I'm not sure Chef, Ansible, etc. will help me, will they? They would require that I code configurations for these machines - which are already totally handled by docker. Can you explain a little bit more about how they can help? Something more relevant to me looks like... mesos has its own ec2 scripts. I could boot a mesos cluster, then use it as the docker cloud provider. But I'm just not clear on how Chef, etc. can help without adding a lot of complexity I do not need. I'm just booting a selenium grid I will throw away when I'm done with it. selenium-docker handles configuration completely.